# Python-Scapy Distinguish between Acesspoint to Station

Tags: python, scapy, wifi

I want to distiniguish between Access Points to Stations while listening to Wi-Fi traffic via python-scapy.

I do it over 802.11b/g/n with management frames, but it doesn't work over 5GHz (802.11ac/a) as I don't see any management frames sent from my iPhone X, but i do see other packets that sent to both directions without having a way to distinguish which one is a wifi client and which is an accesspoint.

When a packet is sent, what is the way to understand wether the sender is an AP or STA?

Best

J

EDIT:

```

From DS to STA via AP
Receiver Address: 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa [STA]
Transmitter Address: a0:4f:d4:2a:f7:d2
Source Address d8:8f:76:88:10:72

From DS to STA via AP
Receiver Address: 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa [STA]
Transmitter Address: a0:4f:d4:2a:f7:d2
Source Address d8:8f:76:88:10:72

From DS to STA via AP
Receiver Address: 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa [STA]
Transmitter Address: a0:4f:d4:2a:f7:d2
Source Address d8:8f:76:88:10:72

From DS to STA via AP
Receiver Address: 01:00:5e:00:00:fb [STA]
Transmitter Address: a0:4f:d4:2a:f7:d2
Source Address d8:8f:76:88:10:72

From DS to STA via AP
Receiver Address: 01:00:5e:00:00:fb [STA]
Transmitter Address: a0:4f:d4:2a:f7:d2
Source Address d8:8f:76:88:10:72

From DS to STA via AP
Receiver Address: 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa [STA]
Transmitter Address: a0:4f:d4:2a:f7:d2
Source Address d8:8f:76:88:10:72

From DS to STA via AP
Receiver Address: 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa [STA]
Transmitter Address: a0:4f:d4:2a:f7:d2
Source Address d8:8f:76:88:10:72

From DS to STA via AP
Receiver Address: 01:00:5e:7f:ff:fa [STA]
Transmitter Address: a0:4f:d4:2a:f7:d2
Source Address d8:8f:76:88:10:72

```

Thats the result i get. most of them are broadcast for some reason

Comment: PS: same question by user closed for lack of infos, https://stackoverflow.com/q/52961162/5459467

Comment: What info exactly are you lacking??

Answer (score 1):

You can process data frames like this:

```
from scapy.all import *

pcap = rdpcap('test_data.pcap')
for pkt in pcap:
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) and pkt.type == 2: #Data frames
        DS = pkt.FCfield & 0x3
        toDS = DS & 0x01 != 0
        fromDS = DS & 0x2 != 0
        if toDS and not fromDS:
            print "From STA to DS via AP"
            print "Receiver Address: %s" % (pkt.addr1)
            print "Transmitter Address: %s" % (pkt.addr2)
            print "Destination Address: %s" % (pkt.addr3)
        if not toDS and fromDS:
            print "From DS to STA via AP"
            print "Receiver Address: %s" % (pkt.addr1)
            print "Transmitter Address: %s" % (pkt.addr2)
            print "Source Address %s" % (pkt.addr3)
        print "\n"
```

Comment: That one is clear, but for some reason my iPhone x doesnt produce Data packets over 5GHz channels (802.11a/ac) only type 1 and subtype 11

Comment: If you generate traffic, like icmp(ping), you do not see data frames?